# Moving multiple faces at once

Tags: faces

I am having trouble trying to move multiple faces at once in different directions.

I can't move all the faces selected without altering the other parts of the model, even though I have already hidden those parts. I also don't know how to move every individual face in particular different directions (in this case, to the center).

Can anyone help me? Thank you. 
[image]

Comment: I am not sure about Move but you can Extrude all faces from the center using the Extrude Individual on the Tool menu when in Edit mode. Center is calculated based on which Faces you select not the Origin Point.

Comment: Sorry, I meant "extrude". How do I use this tool?

Comment: Enter Edit mode, Select the Faces you want to extrude, in the Tool panel (on the left) there is a button "Extrude Individual" click on that and use your mouse to set the Extrude distance.

Comment: That worked. Thanks. I have another problem now, can you help?

Comment: I want to select the faces in a specific pattern, having an unselected face after a selected and vice-versa.

Comment: It is best to ask a new question. But I do know the answer to this one. In Edit mode, with all faces selected, on the Select menu chose Checker Deselect. I created a script that does a very similar job before I found that command. http://www.jumpstation.co.uk/flog/Oct2017.html#p141020171620

Comment: Okay. Thank you for helping.